# Remote login PHP

Tags: php

I am having issues with the code to access a remote website `server2` from another website `server1`. The code I use from inside the server2 to log in is the following code:

```
require_once("http://server2.com/access/models/config.php");
if (!securePage($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){die();}

//Prevent the user visiting the logged in page if he/she is already logged in
if(isUserLoggedIn()) { header("Location: http://server2.com/access/account.php"); die(); }
```

On server2 it looks like I can not use `require_once()` because the page does not pass and when I use `include()`  then prevent the user visiting does not pass. I think I am missing a code like `cURL` or path. Can anybody post the code to call my `server2` from a another remote server1?

Comment: The other got deleted

Comment: require, require_once are variants of include.  There are examples that explain what happens when a remote resource is included: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: It looks like Zim84 answered that, yea now wonder I was having issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't include/require PHP pages from another server because those php-files are getting parsed. You will end up getting the parsed HTML code or non at all if your `config.php` meets minimum safety standards. You'd have to open it differently but be aware that if you can open `config.php` in an easy way remotely, everyone else can too...

I suggest not to use include at all but try a different approach: for example via a php script on that second server that returns you plain text like:

```
login|logout
ok|error
id_Paul23
pwHash_asdf02302afbd33
```

the second items after the `|` represent an alternative response if you have an erroneus login attempt. Your user sends the login-data to your script on server 1 which attempts a login-try on that special script on server 2 which returns the result above and you can then do whatever you want on server 1.

Or better: send/receive the data in a standardized format like JSON. You already have functions in PHP for that: `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` to parse your data.

- Here is an example on how you could do this on a larger scale: http://www.jasny.net/articles/simple-single-sign-on-for-php/
- This article will help you send the request to server2: [How do I send a POST request with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)

Comment: what do you suggest I tried $url and I have tried cURL, do you have any code that might be helpful?

Comment: I've added some suggestions.